# Count json Objects newtonsoft json c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to count how many objects there are i have numbered every objects with a number

```json
{
  "1": {
    "App Name": "7-Zip",
    "App Icon": "",
    "App Link": "http://Example.com/Apps/7-Zip.zip",
    "Category": "Apps"
  },
  "2": {
    "App Name": "AnyDesk",
    "App Icon": "https://anydesk.com/_static/img/favicon/anydesk_icon.png",
    "App Link": "http://Example.com/Apps/AnyDesk.exe",
    "Category": "Apps"
  },
  "3": {
    "App Name": "Brave",
    "App Icon": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/papirus-team/papirus-apps/512/brave-icon.png",
    "App Link": "http://Example.com/Apps/Brave.zip",
    "Category": "Browsers"
  },
  "4": {
    "App Name": "Battle.Net",
    "App Icon": "https://www.macupdate.com/images/icons512/60504.png",
    "App Link": "http://Example.com/Apps/Battle.net.zip",
    "Category": "Battle.Net"
  }
}
```

My C# Code

```cs
var json = File.ReadAllText("D:\\AppJson.json"); 
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

Root Class

```cs
public class _1
{
    [JsonProperty("App Name")]
    public string AppName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("App Icon")]
    public string AppIcon { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("App Link")]
    public string AppLink { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public class _2
{
    [JsonProperty("App Name")]
    public string AppName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("App Icon")]
    public string AppIcon { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("App Link")]
    public string AppLink { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public _1 _1 { get; set; }
    public _2 _2 { get; set; }
}
```

#### Edited:

Added Root Class (Smaller Version)

I want it to make it count every object so I can do if statement on it like `Root.Count;` but I couldn't find a fix for Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Can you post Root class too pls? I don' t think that your json makes any sense.

Comment: What is the use case that you want to solve with this problem? Why do you need to know the count?

Comment: so basically you want to know how many properties are not null after desirialization ?=!

Comment: @PeterCsala i want to count how many objects the json has so i assign every json object to their own button and Picturebox

Comment: your classes `_1` and `_2` have identical properties, why are these separate classes?

Comment: @zaggler i shortened it due to too many code on question normaly its _1_2_3_4

Comment: @MongZhui made them like that so i can easily assign it

Comment: @Zortos If you rename your `_1` class to `Data` then you can issue the following command: `var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, Data>>(json);` After that you can easily map this dictionary into a `List` for example like this:
`new List<Data>(data.Values);` so after you can use it quite easily.

Comment: If you *want just a count* and aren't doing anything with the data, you can use `var childCount = JObject.Parse(json).Children().Count();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this would be much easier with an array instead of an object as the root, you can still do this with the JSON you have.  Instead of creating a `Root` class and individual classes for each property, create a single class representing one of these records:

```
public class MyRecord
{
    [JsonProperty("App Name")]
    public string AppName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("App Icon")]
    public string AppIcon { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("App Link")]
    public string AppLink { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

And then deserialize into a `Dictionary` of those objects:

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, MyRecord>>(json);
```

You can use this `Dictionary` to get the count of records, iterate over them, etc.  In this case the "key" for the `Dictionary` entries is simply the numeric property name in the root JSON object.  (You could also probably use a `Dictionary<int, MyRecord>` as well, if the properties are always integers.)